# How can I index and order based on 'Parent'?

Tags: python, pandas

---

### Issue 1

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Code': [1,2,3,4,5,10,45],'Parent':[2,np.nan,4,2,3,45,2]})
```

[image]

How can I order it based on the Parent Column? I start by saying the first will be the code that does not have a parent, and its 'Index' will be 1. The others will be based on its parents and order of appearance (`df.index`).

Index = parent's Index + '.' + order of appearance

I believe `df.loc[df['Parent'].isna(),'Index'] = 1` is a good start. After that, direct "children" from one will have only one dot, and will be ordered according to the dataframe order, so, we will have

[image]

Since Code 2 is the starting parent, we then move to its children (Codes 1, 4 and 45, in this order).

So, after this iteration, we will have:

[image]

In the next step we will look for codes 1, 4 and 45's children, and so on, until there is no NaN left in the Index column.

**The expected final result (after ordering according to Issue 2) is:**

[image]

We can think of it as chapters, sections and subsections instead of 'Parent'. The ideia is that the Code is inside the Parent, or comes from it. The Parent is the immediate superior.

---

### Issue 2

Also, there is going to be another issue.
Suppose

```
df['Index']= pd.Series(['1.1','1','1.2.1','1.2.16.1','1.2.2.1','1.3.1','1.3'])
```

I want 1.2.16.1 to come after 1.2.2.1
However, if I try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Code': [1,2,3,4,5,10,45],'Parent':[2,np.nan,4,2,3,45,2]})
df['Index'] = pd.Series(['1.1','1','1.2.1','1.2.16.1','1.2.2.1','1.3.1','1.3'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['Index'])
```

What I get is:

[image]

**The expected result is:**

### [image]

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the logic of issue 1? Is not clear to me how you are building the index column values

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: yes, now is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it, not efficient, but effective

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from natsort import natsorted
df = pd.DataFrame({'Code': [1,2,3,4,5,10,45],'Parent':[2,np.nan,4,2,3,45,2]})

#First I gor the Indexes for the Codes that don't have Parents, those will be 1,2,3,...
df.loc[df['Parent'].isna(),"Index"] = range(1,len(df.loc[df['Parent'].isna(), df.columns[1]])+1)

#Then I saved the columns from the dataframe at this point
initial_columns = df.columns

#Then I converted Index column to string and split on dots, since the values were like 1.0, 2.0, etc.
df['Index']  = df['Index'].astype(str).str.split('.',expand = True)

#Then I started a loop that will go on until there is no more "nan" in the index column

while (len(df.loc[df['Index'] == "nan",'Index']) > 0):
    #Since the Codes that have 'Index' will now be the Parents, I put them in another dataframe so I could merge
    df2 = df[['Index','Code']]
    df2 = df2.rename(columns = {'Index':'Parent Index','Code': 'Parent Code'})
    df = df.merge(df2, left_on = 'Parent' , right_on = 'Parent Code',how = 'left')

    #Then I created a Auxiliar Column for each Parent in which I make a range depend on the number of ocurrances
    for i in range(len(df2.loc[df2['Parent Index'] != "nan", "Parent Index"].unique())):
        df.loc[(df['Index'] == "nan") & (df['Parent Index'] == df2.loc[df2['Parent Index'] != "nan", "Parent Index"].unique()[i]), 'Aux Col' + str(i)] = \
                                range(1,len(df.loc[(df['Index'] == "nan") & (df['Parent Index'] == df2.loc[df2['Parent Index'] != "nan", "Parent Index"].unique()[i]),df2.columns[1]])+1)
    #Then I, again, split on dots, this time right split (so, if I have, 1.2.2.1.0 (this .0 comes from the range), I stay with 1.2.2.1)
        df['Aux Col' + str(i)] = df['Aux Col' + str(i)].astype(str).str.rsplit('.',n = 1,expand = True)

    #Now I just define the Index for the new children (currently na, but with Parents not na)     
        df.loc[(df['Index'] == "nan") & (df['Parent Index'] == df2.loc[df2['Parent Index'] != "nan", "Parent Index"].unique()[i]), 'Index'] = \
                                df['Parent Index'].astype(str) + "." + df['Aux Col'+str(i)].astype(str)
    #Then I clean the dataset, since I created a big mess and a lot of columns
    df = df[initial_columns]
# Finally, just reordering as WeNYoBen suggested.
df = df.set_index('Index').reindex(natsorted(df.Index)).reset_index()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way using `natsorted`

```
from natsort import natsorted

df = df.set_index('Index').reindex(natsorted(df.Index)).reset_index()
Out[42]: 
      Index  Code  Parent
0         1     2     NaN
1       1.1     1     2.0
2     1.2.1     3     4.0
3   1.2.2.1     5     3.0
4  1.2.16.1     4     2.0
5       1.3    45     2.0
6     1.3.1    10    45.0
```

Comment: nice :) good catch ... also i guess `index = df['Code'] + '.' + df['Parent'].replacena('0')`

Comment: You solved the second issue! But the starting point is `df = pd.DataFrame({'Code': [1,2,3,4,5,10,45],'Parent':[2,np.nan,4,2,3,45,2]})`. `df['Index']` is to be created. Sorry for not being clear.